# How many Assumptions can I make in Proof by Induction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, solution-verification, problem-solving

Let's say I want to prove by mathematical induction that a statement involving $n$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb N$. A classic example is proving that
$$\sum_{r=1}^nr=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$$
The base step is trivial. This requires only $1$ assumption to prove by induction; namely that for a given $n=k$ the statement holds and then we go on to prove that this implies the statement is also true for $n=k+1$. But what if one assumption is not enough to prove the general case? Let's say to prove the general case I needed to assume the statement held for $2$ values: $n=k-1$ and $n=k$ and then I used this to prove that the result follows for $n=k+1$. Would that be ok?

More generally, for a proof by induction must I only make one assumption or am I permitted to use many? Please explain why, whatever the answer is.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have shown $n=k-1,n=k$-cases implies $n=k+1$-case and base case $n=0$ and $n=1$, this is a valid induction proof.

Comment: You might also want to read about strong induction - in the inductive step you can actually assume that _all_ previous cases are true.

Comment: @csch2 woah, sounds cool, thanks for the reference!

Comment: I like this question.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah thanks, I appreciate it!

Comment: I find it's sometimes useful to realize that a proof by induction can be thought of as a proof that the set of counterexamples must be a set of positive integers with no least element.  Such a set must be empty.  In other words, suppose $P(n)$ is the smallest counterexample.  Your base case shows that $n \neq 1$, so for some positive integer $m, n=m+1$.  But if $n$ is the **smallest** counterexample, then $P(m)$ must be true.  Thus, if you can prove that $P(m) \Rightarrow P(m+1)=P(n)$, then you have a contradiction because $P(n)$ isn't a counterexample after all, contrary to your assumption.

Comment: @RobertShore I read this idea in a book a few months ago and didn't get it; thanks to you I finally do, thanks so much for helping me understand it!

Comment: When you think about a proof by induction this way, strong induction becomes much more intuitive.  If $P(n)$ is the **smallest** counterexample, then you're free to assume, if necessary, that $P(m)$ holds for all $m \lt n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can! But then you must have two base cases. For example, if you show that ${n=k}$ and ${n=k+1}$ both being true would imply that ${n=k+2}$ is true, and you have two base cases (such as ${n=0}$ and ${n=1}$ for example) then that would imply the case for ${n=2}$ is true. Then it being true for ${n=1}$ and ${n=2}$ would imply it's true for ${n=3}$. Then for $4$, then for $5$... etc etc. It's the same principle

Comment: So however many assumptions I make I must have the same amount of base cases?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent exactly yes. It's your base cases that "build" the rest of the cases up

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, that is incredibly helpful :))

Comment: @A-LevelStudent no problem!

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the above answer, there is a form of induction called "course-of-values" or "complete" or "strong" induction that requires no base cases. It says that to prove $P(n)$ for all $n$, it is sufficient to prove that for all $n$, $P(n)$ holds, if $P(m)$ holds for all $m < n$. In symbols:
$$
(\forall n ((\forall m < n P(m)) \Rightarrow P(n))) \Rightarrow (\forall n P(n))
$$
You can use this, for example, to prove that any natural number $n > 1$ is a product of primes. (This form of induction sneaks the base case in secretly because "$\forall m < n P(m)$" is automatically true when $n = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

There's no upper limit on how many base cases you are allowed to use, although too many can be unnecessary and more than you need. The way to tell how many cases you need is to formulate your problem as a recurrence relation. For example, your given series can be represented as $$a_{n+1}=a_n+(n+1)$$ with $a_1=1$. The number of $a_k$ terms on the RHS of the recurrence equation represents the number of base cases you need to solve any such recurrence relation.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this technique, it may come in useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a webpage talking about different type of [Induction](https://qcweb.qc.edu.hk/math/Resource/AL/Different%20kinds%20of%20Mathematical%20Induction.pdf). 
You maybe looking for Second Principle of Mathematical Induction, which make multiple assumptions.